# Modify User-Agent for Windows Phone WebBrowser Control

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

We have a WebBrowser embedded in our Windows Phone 7x application. This WebBrowser is pointed at our web servers. We need to be able to differentiate between a request coming from the app and a request coming from the native browser (or a WebBrowser embedded in another app, for instance). To do this we'd like to modify the User-Agent of all HTTP requests coming from said WebBrowser.

However, I can't find a way to do this. My initial thought was simply to override the Navigate functions adding "additionalHeaders." Unfortunately the WebBrowser class is sealed, so that option wasn't an option at all. I've searched high and low for a property or handler that's exposed that I might be able to take advantage of to no avail.

So, in short, is there a way to modify the User-Agent for a WebBrowser for all outbound HTTP requests?

Comment: @Michal: Did you get answer of your problem? I am also having similar poblem.(still looking for answer?)Can you please help me out.

Comment: @Invincible Nope, no luck. Hopefully in later releases the WebBrowser class will be un-sealed, although I doubt it. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but in case this is of use to anyone, you could always use this for the WebBrowser's navigating event:

```
    void wb_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Uri.ToString().Contains("!!!"))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            string url = e.Uri.ToString();
            if (url.Contains("?"))
                url = url + "&!!!";
            else
                url = url + "?!!!";
            wb.Navigate(new Uri(url), null, "User-Agent: " + "Your User Agent");
        }
    }
```

You just add "!!!" to all the urls for navigations that have your custom user agent. If the URL doesn't contain "!!!", it is a request from a clicked link and the WebBrowser cancels the navigation, and re-navigates with your custom user agent and "!!!" in the query string.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a similar approach to msbg, where you store the URL in memory to avoid double checking it, and avoid modifying it with !!!.  However, that approach doesn't preserve POST data, so it won't help me.

```
List<string> recentlyRequestedUrls = new List<string>();

    void wb_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!recentlyRequestedUrls.Contains(e.Uri.ToString()))
        {
            //new request, reinitiate it ourselves and save that we did to avoid infinite loop.
            e.Cancel = true;
            string url = e.Uri.ToString();
            recentlyRequestedUrls.Add(url);
            webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(url), null, "User-Agent: Your_User_Agent");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I have not had any need for POST data, it can  be added in the second Navigate parameter. You'd have to figure out how to get it though...

Answer (score 0):

Set the user agent through additional headers, when invoking the **Navigate** method. Details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626636%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but as I understand it this doesn't modify the headers for subsequent requests initiated by the user in the browser window (i.e. clicking on a link). As noted above, we tried to intercept all Navigate requests by extending WebBrowser, but unfortunately the class is sealed.